# Harry Potter Fanfic based on Order of the Phoenix where the trio break someone out of Azkaban and become Animagi

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

Way back in 2013, I read a great novel length Harry Potter fan fiction. I want to reread it but I can't find it online since there have been many, many fanfics written since then.

It was based on book 5 (*Order of the Phoenix*) and I'm pretty sure it was titled the same. In the book Harry, Ron, and Hermione go to Azkaban to break someone out. The three also learn to be Animagi. I know it was quite long, reaching over 30 chapters. It was also written before 2013 and I'm pretty sure the author also wrote fanfics of the 6th and 7th book as well.

Comment: This is a nice start but could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11922/58193) to see if there is anything else you can remember that you could [edit] in? For example, can you remember where you read it? You have some general description here but can you remember any specific plot points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be the work sometimes titled *[Fake Order of the Phoenix](https://thoughtsonthingsandstuff.com/the-book-of-abraham-and-the-order-of-the-phoenix/)* by Orion11?

> The story was amazing. It started, like all Harry Potter stories do, at the Dursley household. Many other elements of the story made me feel right at home in the wizarding world of Harry Potter – Hermione’s brusk know-it-all attitude, the quirky Weasleys and the amazing description of magic spells, mystical artifacts, dark stories from the years before, and Harry Potter’s brave yet vulnerable character. There were some new surprises in store as well, including a Dudley Dursley who had softened his attitude towards Harry, the three major characters becoming Animagi themselves, each learning how to transform themselves into an animal like Sirius Black who could turn himself into a dog.
>
> I eagerly plowed through the whole book. It turned out that the “order” in the Order of the Phoenix was a special endowment granted by the Golden Phoenix long ago to Garde Delafer. Garde had helped to save the Phoenixes at a time when they were hunted for sport and their healing power. After saving the Golden Phoenix, this magical beast blessed him so that every one of his descendants would have the power to order the healing of one person or creature who could be revived – even from death. That was the Order of the Phoenix – and all of Garde’s descendants were said to belong to the Order of the Phoenix! Guess who happened to be in that Order – Harry Potter!
>
> It is a good thing too, because during their adventure in this book, Harry decides to use his order to revive his mother Lilly. Just as he is about to do so, Voldemort appears in the form of a black phoenix and steals Harry’s order! There are magic battles, Dragon duels and a lot of drama – until finally Voldemort unleashes an Avade Kadavra killing curse which hits Hermoine – killing her instantly! Harry is devastated, and the Golden Phoenix himself appears and restores Harry’s Order allowing Hermoine to be brought back to life.

The review doesn't mention it, but you get Azkaban break-out plans in the [full text](https://archive.org/stream/FakeOrderOfThePheonix/Fake+order+of+the+pheonix_djvu.txt).

> "One last question," he said. "Why did we clone you?"
> "Because we're going to Azkaban to rescue Sirius and Lupin," said Harry. Ron's clone
> smiled and nodded.
> "Yeah, why risk our necks when we can make clones of ourselves and let them do it?" he
> said, laughing afterwards.

I found it by searching for *harry potter fanfic "order of the phoenix" azkaban animagi*

Comment: Yes, I believe this is it. Thank you. I'll have to read a few chapters of it to be sure, but  I vaguely remember some of the other details from the description.